# Fact table joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

I have two facttables A and B.

[image]

A has a positionkey column in it and B has 4 columns called position_1,position_2,
position_3,position_4 and has an indicator of that position. For eg, if B has 2 under position_1 it means two people with position 1 were assigned. if B has 1 under position_2 it means one person with position 2 was assigned. 
I would want to join these two tables by position and other keys.

Is there a possibility to do this?

Comment: which is the RDBMS

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: are you using the positionkey column to decide which of the position_# columns to look at?

Comment: Yes, So if position =  3 in A, I know that it should be mapped to position_3 in B

Comment: Desired results would really help.  I don't get the data model.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CASE in your JOIN conditions.

```
ON a.PositionValue = CASE
  WHEN a.PositionKey=1 THEN b.Position_1
  WHEN a.PositionKey=2 THEN b.Position_2
  etc...
END
```